# Manipulating color theme inside color function

Tags: plotting, functions, color, legending

I have the following code:

```
f[x_, c_] = Solve[x^2 - y^2 == c^2, y]

Plot[y /. f[x, 2], {x, -40, 40}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-40, 40}, {-40, 40}}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["BrassTones"][y]], 
 GridLines -> Full]
```

Which gives me the following plot:

[image: brass tones]

I tried to find similar single-colour gradient themes like `BrassTones` with dark shades at the corner and light shaded at the centre but to no avail. How can I use single colour themes found in Mathematica like `CherryTones` or `ValentineTones` in a similar manner as above? Any other methods to design similar palettes are most welcome!

Comment: a simple way is to use `Function[{x, y}, Blend[{Black, Yellow, Black}, y]]` (replace `Yellow` with desired color)

Comment: use `Grid[Prepend[{"name", "image",   "blend arguments"}][{#, ColorData[#, "Image"],  DataPaclets`ColorData`GetBlendArgument[#]} & /@   ColorData["*Tones"]], Alignment -> Left]` to see the colors `Blend`ed by color schemes `"*Tones"`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, just a follow up question- How do I use such gradient scheme in PlotLegends as well if I have multiple plots? Would be really helpful if you could post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[cF, gradientLegend]

cF[clr_] := Blend[{Black, clr, Black}, #] &;

gradientLegend[lbl_, cf_] := Placed[Labeled[
    Graphics[{Thick, Line[Thread[{Subdivide[10], 0}], 
       VertexColors -> (cf /@ Subdivide[10])]}, AspectRatio -> 1/50, 
     ImageSize -> {50, 20}], lbl, Right], Right];

Plot[y /. f[x, 2], {x, -40, 40}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-40, 40}, {-40, 40}}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, cF[Yellow]@y],
 GridLines -> Full, 
 PlotLegends -> gradientLegend[y /. f[x, 2], cF[Yellow]]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

For multiple functions:

```
Show @ 
 MapThread[
   Plot[#, {x, -40, 40}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotRange -> {{-40, 40}, {-40, 40}}, 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, cF[#2]@y], 
     GridLines -> Full, 
     PlotLegends -> gradientLegend[#3, cF[#2]]] &]@
 {
  {y /. f[x, 2], y /. f[x, 10]}, (*functions*)
  {Yellow, Red}, (*colors*)
  {y /. f[x, 2], "func2"} (*legend labels*)
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @codebpr, you are welcome. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

A variation using `LinearGradientImage`:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_, c_] := Solve[x^2 - y^2 == c^2, y]

(* custom color function *)
cf[x_] := Blend[{Red, Green, Black}, x]; 

MapThread[Plot[#1
    , {x, -40, 40}
    , AspectRatio -> 1
    , PlotRange -> {{-40, 40}, {-40, 40}}
    , ColorFunction -> #2
    , GridLines -> All
    , PlotLegends -> Placed[
      Legended[LinearGradientImage[#3, {60, 3}]
       , #1 // TraditionalForm], After]
    ] &
  , {{y /. f[x, 2], y /. f[x, 10], 20 Tanh[x/9]}
   , {(ColorData["Rainbow"][#2] &), (Hue[#2] &), (cf[#1] &)}
   , {"Rainbow", Hue, cf}
   }
  ] // Show
```

---

[image]